# Why does adding this javascript for FlashGallery cause my background image to shift up?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash

I've added a flash gallery to my site and the required script is causing the background image to shift.

You can see the page here: http://www.arbitersoflight.net/media/screens.html

The script in question is the "swfobject.js". I've determined this by adding/removing the

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/flashgallery/swfobject.js"></script>
```

line to my site (which is required to run the gallery). Obviously, due to the layout of my site, I cannot having the background being moved...so this is very annoying. Unfortunately I know next to nothing about coding so I lack the skills to find the problem myself. I would really appreciate any help you guys can give me here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this is happening, but if you add the following CSS to the following tags it will fix it:

```
#header { position:relative; top:15px; }
.scroll-pane { position:relative; top:-15px; }
```

**EDIT:**

Another reason this might be happening is from white-space in this script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="sourcecode">
        $(function()
        {
            $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
        });
</script>
```

A possible way to fix this would be to save that code to a file and include it as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jscrollpane/jquery.jscrollpane.init.js"></script>
```

Comment: That does help counter the offset, but it doesn't fix it completely. It still causes the background to be out of alignment.

Comment: It looks fine on my system, so I guess I'm not sure what the problem is.  On my end the girl on the right is lined up.

Comment: Here's the problem if I add the relative position: http://img140.imageshack.us/img140/8269/33493704.jpg I don't think it's the other script code as that exists on all the other pages and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: You need to add that position code to `#header` as well and it seems to align correctly for me.

Comment: I completely tarded out and didn't add the tag to #header. Doing this made it much closer but still not quite perfect. The larger problem though is that this messes up other pages that don't use that script. I put an email in to the developers of the gallery, I may  just have to find another solution for an image gallery though. Thanks for all of your help though.